# applying a pass only on execution paths

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

I have a pass that is analyzing the entire module (using `runOnFunction()`). But I want to apply it on each execution path. By execution path I mean the sequence of instructions starting from a point in the program (annotated with start) till a termination point of the program (annotated with end).

I assume I have to divide my module into functions by constructing a CallGraph and then divide every function into instructions by construction CFG-s in the nodes of the previous mentioned CallGraph. I assume that the execution paths from a node that I choose are all the paths finishing in the CallGraph leaves (I should be able to communicate between CFG-s). From that node I can see all the paths by using a graph search algorithm.

Is there a possibility to replace the `runOnFunction()` / `runOnModule()` method with something user defined, like `runOnExecutionPath()` ? And if so, there is in LLVM a structure that is appropriate to store execution paths? 
Another possibility can be to use `getAnalysis<CallGraph>` or `getAnalysis<CFG>`? I am confused.

Thank you a lot for any advice !

Comment: It would help if you could define very explicitly what you mean by "execution path" in this context

Comment: I updated into the question. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean it cross-function? Note that this isn't easy to figure out due to function pointers

Comment: First I will assume that the start point and the end points are in the same function for simplicity.