# LLVM traverse CFG

Tags: llvm

I want to apply a DFS traversing algorithm on a CFG of a function. Therefore, I need the internal representation of the CFG. I need oriented edges and spotted `MachineBasicBlock::const_succ_iterator`. It is there a way to get the CFG with oriented edges by using a `FunctionPass`, instead of a `MachineFunctionPass`? The reason why I want this is that I have problems using `MachineFunctionPass`. I have written several complex passes till now, but I cannot run a `MachineFunctionPass` pass.

I found that : "A `MachineFunctionPass` is a part of the LLVM code generator that executes on the machine-dependent representation of each LLVM function in the program. Code generator passes are registered and initialized specially by `TargetMachine::addPassesToEmitFile` and similar routines, so they cannot generally be run from the opt or bugpoint commands."...So how I can run a `MachineFunctionPass`?

When I was trying to run with opt a simple `MachineFunctionPass`, I got the error :

```
Pass 'mycfg' is not initialized.
Verify if there is a pass dependency cycle.
Required Passes:
opt: PassManager.cpp:638: void llvm::PMTopLevelManager::schedulePass(llvm::Pass*): Assertion `PI && "Expected required passes to be initialized"' failed.
```

So I have to initialize the pass. But in my all other passes I did not any initialization and I don't want to use `INITIALIZE_PASS` since I have to recompile the llvm file that is keeping the pass registration... Is there a way to keep using `static RegisterPass` for a `MachineFunctionPass` ? I mention that if I change to `FunctionPass`, I have no problems, so indeed it might be an opt problem.

I have started another pass for CallGraph. I am using `CallGraph &CG = getAnalysis<CallGraph>();` efficiently. It is a similar way of getting CFG-s? What I found till now are `succ_iterator/succ_begin/succ_end` which are from `CFG.h`, but I think I still have to get the CFG analysis somehow.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: How `MachineBasicBlock` is relevant to an IR? And what else do you need besides succ_iterator or pred_iterator? IR is already a CFG.

Comment: Ok. So I can apply directly succ_iterator? I don't need to get somehow the CFG analysis, the internal representation of CFG? If it is already there, I will try to use it and update my question (I had some problems trying this approach).

Comment: No, you don't need a separate analysis pass to get CFG. There are dedicated passes for obtaining DominatorTree, DominanceFrontier, etc., but CFG is already there by design. If you want examples on how to iterate over CFG, take a look at, say, `DominanceFrontier.cpp`.

Comment: Thank you for the DominanceFrontier.cpp example!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may have some terms mixed up. Basic blocks within each function are already arranged in a kind-of CFG, and LLVM provides you the tools to traverse that. See [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367585/applying-a-pass-only-on-execution-paths), for example.

`MachineFunction` lives on a different level, and unless you're doing something very special, this is not the level you should operate on. It's too low-level, and too target specific. There's some overview of the levels [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/11/24/life-of-an-instruction-in-llvm/)